# Reference two versions of the same assembly in a Xamarin app

Tags: visual-studio, reference, xamarin

I'm trying to create a Xamarin App that uses a reference to an assembly that requires Service.Model v 4.0.

Xamarin requires Service.Model v 2.0, but I cannot add them both via Add reference or Nuget.

I'm trying to figure out a way to have them both.
In VS I don't have the option to add an app.config.
Which options do I have?

Comment: I don't believe that Xamarin supports Service Model 4.0.  Are you trying to add an assembly from Windows BCL?  If so, that won't work.

Comment: It's another assembly required to connect to an application endpoint, so there are not so many ways around it. Need to handle auth, SOAP payloads and methods with custom code then